# Improve update performance in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I've generated two temporary tables, also assigned a primary key to the generated tables - to get an index on them.

Like this on both:

`ALTER TABLE TEMP_MEASURINGS ADD PRIMARY KEY (MEASURINGID)`

`ALTER TABLE TEMP_VALUES ADD PRIMARY KEY (<some_other_col>)`

The two temp-tables are related by a date and another id as you can see by the query. Now I need to update the "measuringid" in TEMP_VALUES based on the other table.

Can I make this query go faster in any way?

```
UPDATE TEMP_VALUES v 
SET v.MEASURINGID = 
(
    SELECT MEASURINGID 
    FROM TEMP_MEASURINGS m 
    WHERE m.MEASURDATE = v.MEASUREDATE 
    AND m.ORDERID = v.ORDERID
)
```

The tables needs to be generated first, so I can't do an insert directly.

`SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TEMP_VALUES` ~6M

`SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TEMP_MEASURINGS` ~1.5M

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query is going to be slow, because so many rows are being updated.

You can speed it with an index on `TEMP_MEASURINGS(MEASUREDATE, ORDERID, MEASURINGID)`.  This is a covering index for the subquery.  The lookups should be fast.

You might find it faster just to create a new table:

```
create new_temp_values as 
    select v.*, m.measuringid           
    from temp_values v left join
         temp_measurings m
         on v.measuredate = m.measuredate and v.orderid = m.orderid;
```

The same index will work here (you can adjust the `select` columns to be what you really need).

Typically, creating a new table is much, much faster than updating all or even a significant number of rows in a given table.

Comment: It was by far much faster to generate another table instead of updating all rows. Also I created the suggested index. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try with below merge for peformance:

```
MERGE TEMP_VALUES v
USING (SELECT MEASURINGID,
              MEASURDATE,
              ORDERID
       FROM TEMP_MEASURINGS) m
ON 
   m.MEASURDATE = v.MEASUREDATE 
   AND m.ORDERID = v.ORDERID
WHEN MATCHED THEN
       UPDATE
       SET v.MEASURINGID = m.MEASURINGID;
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of updating all records you can update records that exists in temp table:

```
UPDATE TEMP_VALUES v 
    SET v.MEASURINGID = 
    (
        SELECT MEASURINGID 
        FROM TEMP_MEASURINGS m 
        WHERE m.MEASURDATE = v.MEASUREDATE 
        AND m.ORDERID = v.ORDERID
    )
    where 
    exists (select 1 from TEMP_VALUES ttt, TEMP_MEASURINGS ttm WHERE ttm.MEASURDATE = ttt.MEASUREDATE 
        AND ttm.ORDERID = ttt.ORDERID and ttt.ID = v.ID)
```